# Принять запрос multipart/form-data в .Net Core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp

Нужно вот при помощи Soap Ui отправить запрос в приложение .Net Core. В запросе есть какие то данные формата json + прикрепленный файл.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
[Route("betrsign"), AllowAnonymous, ApiController]
public sealed class ServiceController : Controller
```

и у него есть post метод

```
[HttpPost("service"), DisableRequestSizeLimit]
[DisableFormValueModelBinding]
public async Task<ActionResult> Service()
```

Нигде не могу найти и не получается получить ни данные, ни контент файла.
Еще как вариант, мб я что неправильно шлю через Soap? Как через HttpContext.Request.Body или как то так получить все необходимое?

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте атрибут `[Consumes("multipart/form-data")]` для метода

Получать его вот так -> `public async Task<ActionResult> Service([FromForm] Model model)`

Предварительно описав модель того, что получаем